# UIView alpha is disappering after UIButton is clicked

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uikit

I have a container `UIView` and a `UIView` with `alpha 0.7f` in it, also a custom `UIButton` with image added to that container `UIView`. Now whenever I click on the button a big square chunk on transparent `UIView` disappears and stays that way. I have no idea why this happens. Can anyone help me figure this out?

```
UIWindow* window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];

UIView *viewTestOverViewContainer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:window.bounds];

UIView *viewOverlay = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:viewTestOverViewContainer.frame];
viewOverlay.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
viewOverlay.alpha = 0.7;
[viewTestOverViewContainer addSubview:viewOverlay];

float x = (window.bounds.size.width/2)-98;
float y = (window.bounds.size.height/2)-98;
UIView *viewTestPicContainer = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 204, 204)];
viewTestPicContainer.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
viewTestPicContainer.layer.cornerRadius = viewTestPicContainer.frame.size.width / 2;
viewTestPicContainer.clipsToBounds = YES;
viewTestPicContainer.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[viewTestPicContainer setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];

UIImageView *imgViewTestPic = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2, 2, 200, 200)];
imgViewTestPic.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"portrait_eyes_14.jpg"];

imgViewTestPic.layer.cornerRadius = imgViewTestPic.frame.size.width / 2;
imgViewTestPic.clipsToBounds = YES;
imgViewTestPic.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[imgViewTestPic setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
[viewTestPicContainer addSubview:imgViewTestPic];
[viewTestOverViewContainer addSubview:viewTestPicContainer];

UIButton *btnLeftArrow = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btnLeftArrow.frame = CGRectMake(46, 275, 12, 20);
[btnLeftArrow setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"popup-left-arrow"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[viewTestOverViewContainer addSubview:btnLeftArrow];

UIButton *btnRightArrow = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btnRightArrow.frame = CGRectMake(270, 275, 12, 20);
[btnRightArrow setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"popup-right-arrow"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[viewTestOverViewContainer addSubview:btnRightArrow];

[window addSubview:viewTestOverViewContainer];
```

**Before:**
[image: before]

**After clicking the left arrow button:**
[image: after]

Comment: Ensure that when you post a programming question, you provide the relevant parts of your program (show some code).

Comment: I tested your code on iOS 7.1 and 8.1 and it works as expected. Is there more code where you set other properties of your views or buttons?

Comment: @anka : No, this is the only code. I also tried to add a image with opacity instead of setting alpha but that also have same problem.

Comment: Ok, on which iOS version did you run this code and when do you execute this code (i.e. in `viewDidLoad` method)? Is there any other code executed when activating the button?

Comment: @anka : I ran it on 7.1.2 iOS version. Code that I posted is executed when user clicks "Push It!" button. No other code is running when button is clicked.

Comment: @anka : Another interesting fact is that when I take a screenshot in device, missing chunk of UIView appears in screenshot.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce the problem at all. I am sorry. Please post your solution/error if you found it.